# PyQt5 Combobox HorizontalScrollBar overlaps last item

Tags: combobox, pyqt5, horizontal-scrolling

PyQt5 HorizontalScrollBar on combobox overlaps last item

This is [without scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2f90.png)

[This is after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdnPk.png)
`combo.view().setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)`

And also if i try `ScrollBarAsNeeded` i get [this bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbMHz.png)

Please help me to fix that issue

Thanks!

I found ([Allow horizontal scrolling in a QComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569433/allow-horizontal-scrolling-in-a-qcombobox))

It helped me a lot but if combo has 2-4 items it's starting overlap last item.

And if `combo.view().setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)` then `VerticalScrollBar` also appears but his default policy is `ScrollBarAsNeeded` as i know

#### Edited...

This a pretty simple example of issue:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.combo_box_issue = None
        self.combo_box_good = None
        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        # bad combo
        self.combo_box_issue = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box_issue.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.combo_box_issue.setGeometry(170, 100, 120, 30)
        self.combo_box_issue.setEditable(True)
        view = QListView(self)
        geek_list = ["Geek", "Geeky GeekGeeky GeekGeeky GeekGeeky"]
        self.combo_box_issue.addItems(geek_list)
        self.combo_box_issue.setView(view)
        view.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        # good combo
        self.combo_box_good = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box_good.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.combo_box_good.setGeometry(170, 200, 120, 30)
        self.combo_box_good.setEditable(True)
        view = QListView(self)
        geek_list = ["Geek", "Geeky GeekGeeky GeekGeeky GeekGeekyGeekGeeky GeekGeeky GeekGeekyGeekGeeky GeekGeeky GeekGeekyGeekGeeky GeekGeeky GeekGeeky"]
        self.combo_box_good.addItems(geek_list)
        self.combo_box_good.setView(view)
        view.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

So if i clicked a bad combo first time i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNwYB.png).
But if i clicked one more time i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3gSq.png). HorizontalScroll overlaps last item of combo

And when i use policy `ScrollBarAsNeeded` i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cjMp.png)

Why it's starting overlaps? Why verticalscrollbar is born?

Comment: What do you mean by "if combo has 2-4 items it's starting overlap last item"? Can you please provide a [mre] that also shows the actual need for the horizontal scroll bar? Because right now your images only show text that never needs it.

Comment: Are you sure that you just don't want to show a *wider* popup? By default, QComboBox *tries* to show itself as wide as possible, but the layouts may make it smaller than expected, with the result that the popup is limited by that width; a better solution is to make the view wider, not to always show its horizontal scroll bar, unless the item width is *really* that big (which doesn't seem a good idea from the UX perspective). Also, you're not using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), which would eventually solve the problem, as fixed geometries are almost **never** a good idea.